# Sum of array values where key is greater than certain value

Tags: php

In PHP, How do you sum the values of an array where the key is greater than a number (e.g., 20)?

Note: Both keys are values are numeric.

Comment: I assume the keys are not continuous?

Comment: correct, they're in order but there are keys missing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key > 20)
        $sum += $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
  if( $key > 20 )
    $sum += $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(...);
$n = 0;
foreach($arr as $an => $a) {
    if($an > 20) {
        $n += $a;
    }
}
echo $n;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start your loop from your start key:

```
$sum = 0;
$keyStart = 20;
for($i = $keyStart, $c = count($array); $i < $c; $i++) {
    $sum += $arr[$i];
}
```

Please note that I assume that your array is numerically indexed and array keys are continuous here.